# Winforms datagridview wont load data if some data is null

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 tables in my database. School (one to many) - Students (one to one) - Money. It all works fine, however I have a datagridview which inner joins all three tables, but it will not show any data that has nothing in money table. So all students that has saved info in money table too will show up, but I want to see those as well which has no data in money table as well. Is it how it should be? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From there [Using Outer Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Inner joins return rows only when there is at least one row from both
>   tables that matches the join condition. Inner joins eliminate the rows
>   that do not match with a row from the other table.

If you want show rows which hasn't `Money` records use LEFT JOIN in your sql query.

```sql
SELECT sch.SomeColumn
FROM School sch
INNER JOIN Students sts ON <some students condition>
LEFT JOIN Money m ON <some money condition>
```

Citation and example are from Sql Server, but apply for MySql too

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by using outer join with Linq:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

var query = from person in people
            join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
            from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

If you use SQL only than you need to use Outer Join in SQL.